Why Marquee in HTML and CSS context is named that way?
I am kind of curious as to why this feature is name Marquee?
It is an animation of a text scrolling horizontally or vertically across the screen.
I searched through the internet and I got nothing.

You know the billboards in front of Broadway theaters that show what's playing, sometimes in a scrolling line like ticker tape?  Those are marquees.

There is no  element and there never has been--sort of. No HTML specification has ever had one since the beginning of time. The only reason the current spec contains a reference to it is to mark it as obsolete (not just deprecated as MDN wrongly marks it).

Traditionally it refers to a large banner-like sign or display above the entrance of  a theater or a building. These signs often feature moving or flashing text to attract attention, much like how the marquee element makes text or other content scroll across screen. It is however now obsolete and not recommended for recent web development
